# Adding `v-model` to Symfony `ChoiceType` radio buttons

Tags: php, vue.js, symfony

What's the easiest way to add Vue.js `v-model` to Symfony radio buttons (i.e. [ChoiceType](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html) with `'expanded' => true, 'multiple' => false`)? Vue.js expects `v-model` on *each* `<input type="radio">`, see https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#radio

My solution/workaround is to render each radio button with `form_widget()` in Twig:

```
{% for foo in form.foo %}
    {{ form_widget(foo, {'attr': {'v-model':'foo'}} ) }}
{% endfor %}
```

But is there a way to get them all at once with `form_row()`?

`attr` or `row_attr` are not working:

```
{{ form_row(form.foo, {'attr': {'v-model':'foo'}} ) }}
{# or #}
{{ form_row(form.foo, {'row_attr': {'v-model':'foo'}} ) }}
```

Both result in `v-model` being added to a *container*:

```html
<div v-model="foo">
```

Comment: Since Symfony 4.3, the row_attr option permits to add attributes.
Here : https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-3-more-form-improvements#row-attributes-in-form-themes

Answer (score 1):

The solution is [`choice_attr`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-attr), but since you need to pass a callback function, you can't do it in Twig, but in your `FormType`:

```php
$builder->add('foo', ChoiceType::class, ['expanded' => true, 'multiple' => false,
    choice_attr' => function($choice, $key, $value): array {
        return ['v-model' => 'foo'];
    },
]);
```